# Error when using Microsoft XML v3.0 or v6.0

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I use Microsoft XML v3.0 reference in VBA to retrieve information from an XML file (API). But sometimes I get the following error: 'user defined type not defined'. When I change the reference to Microsoft XML v6.0, the problem is fixed. But, sometimes, I also get the same error using 6.0. If I switch back to 3.0, the problem is fixed again. So I have to keep changing references in order to avoid the error. Since this file is being used by multiple people, it is impractical to keep switching references. Excel 2013 and 2016 are used to open this file. Once again, I don't always get the error, but sometimes. I really don't know what to do.

Can someone help me out?

Part of code:

```
Public Function Search(sSearchID As String)

Dim sURL As String
Dim sEnv As String
Dim xmlhtp As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument
Dim xmlDocSend As New DOMDocument
Dim xmlDocResponse As DOMDocument
Dim xmlCompanies As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xmlCompany As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlDataItem As IXMLDOMNode
Dim xmlDataItems As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xmlAddressItems As IXMLDOMNodeList

[...]
```

Comment: Without code this is impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: Remove all references to XML, declare your object(s) as Object and use late binding `CreateObject("ClassName")`.

Comment: @KostasK. Thanks. I think this is the solution. However I have a function that takes DOMDocument as parameter. Because of this I don't know how to implement late binding in this function. I cannot create an object because it is already being passed to this function. Function is as follows: `Public Function GetValFromXML(ByVal XML As String, XMLDoc As DOMDocument) As String`

Comment: @jkpieterse  Thanks for your comment. I added a part of the code. Is this enough?

Comment: To create the object use `CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM" )` and then just pass it as object e.g. `GetValFromXML(ByVal XML As String, XMLDoc As Object)`

Comment: @KostasK. Thank you so much! Problem fixed! The file works even though the references are both unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Changing VBA plugin version works for me:

- Windows 7 and before -> Microsoft XML v6.0,
- Windows 8, 10 -> Microsoft XML v3.0